# File sharing access denied error on the Windows 2016 file server. only with ONE folder

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, network-share, file-permissions, file-server

My problem is as followed:

Situation
I have a Windows 2016 file server. In the server role the d: drive is shared. I have many shared folders each with the name of a user and shared to that user. Every user (W10) has a documents folder inside and is made/owned by administrators and linked to the client documents folder.

Problem
One of the users (let's call him Tim) cannot access his shared documents folder (with an access denied error). I as a domain admin cannot see or access the shared folder with \fileserver\userfolders or \fileserver\userfolders\tim\ in explorer. I can access all other user folders.

Things I have tried:

- Delete rights on the fileserver (tim folder), and re-add
- Stop sharing and add the share again (tim folder)
- restart the Server service
- Remake the tim folder

I can see and access the folder when i:

- Rename the folder. \fileserver\userfolders\tim_back
- \IP-address\userfolders\tim
- \fileserver.local\userfolders\tim

What i also tried:
adding: "IP +    fileserver" to the local host file of the client.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Comment: Rest your hosts, if you can conect to the server, it's not DNS. If you can't see a folder, it's ACL/ACE or caching. What does tim's (and your) CSC look like?